# How to do time-lapse photography without intervalometer using Nikon D3300?

Tags: timelapse, intervalometer, nikon-d3300

I need your suggestions and tips on how to do time-lapse photography without using an intervalometer; I am using a Nikon D3300.

Comment: Why do you wish to specifically exclude an intervalometer? It is generally the easiest and, for the most part, cost-effective way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I connected my moto g3 mobile with my nikon d3300 through OTG cable. Then I used an app called DSLRDashboard. It worked. Its great to control my camera through this app. It almost does everything.

Link to download the app:  http://dslrdashboard.info/

Answer (score 0):

You can use your usb cable and connect your camera to the PC, and then use Shell script to shoot with.
I used this to shoot HDR timelapse ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQFYTRffuPc&spfreload=10 : I was just playing around ). What you need is an unix like OS, then library like Gphoto, cable which came with your camera, tripod, and simple shell script where you tell camera to take photos at precise intervals, in this way you have complete control over your camera ( if it is supported, which I believe is ).
If you like, I could post that script & tutorial on my webpage.

Comment: Could you please post the script you refer to. Thanks

Comment: @martinerk0 Would it be easy to do this from an android phone? That seems far more portable. 

Taking a quick look at google play I see some wireless intervalometers for android. I don't know if there is a cabled one in there as well (as d3300 doesn't have wireless by default)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an smarthphone with IR Blaster like Note 4 or Galaxy S5, you can use an App called DSLR Remote to take pictures on your Nikon 3300 every time your phone send the signal according to the settings you pre-configured.

Comment: That works as a remote trigger, but the camera will stop listening for an IR trigger signal after 15 minutes of inactivity, so it doesn't necessarily work for timelapses.